# When is it suitable to use a Sub-Procedure instead of a function?

Tags: vb.net

In my class today I was told change some of my sub-procedures to functions, and when I asked why it's better my teacher struggled to answer, generally, i've always thought that functions should only really be used when a value is returned. In the two examples below; is there one method that should be used over the other, or does it not matter? And if it does matter why?
Thanks in advance.

Method 1 (Sub-Proc):

```
Sub EncryptString(ByVal unkString, ByRef encryptedString)
    For i = 1 To Len(unkString)
        encryptedString += "*"
    Next
End Sub
```

Method 2 (Function):
[In main I assign the variable "encryptedString" to this function].

```
Function encryptString(ByVal unkString) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(unkString)
        encryptString += "*"
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: More important would be to set `Option Strict On`.  That method *would* be better as a function returning a new string.  Using an argument for the return is a convoluted way to do something simple. `Return newString` is the more common syntax these days than the old fashioned assign return value to method name version   (And that is not encryption at all)

Comment: Please please please, if you learn anything from us, let it be `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On`, preferably set as defaults for all new projects, so you don't forget.

Comment: Btw you could write the function more cleanly as:     `Function encryptString(unkString As String)` 
        `Return String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", unkString.Length))` 
    `End Function`

Comment: @djv `Function encryptString(unkString As String) As String`

Comment: @LarsTech right, copy paste mistake, now it's too late to edit ><

Comment: @Plutonix also I know that is not encryption , it's what our teacher told us to name it. Maybe obfuscateString is a more appropriate name.

Comment: It is not even obfuscation...it is just creating a string of asterisks with no other meaning or value hidden or otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood what they're trying to tell you. In your `Function` example there is no difference. What your teacher is expecting is like this:

```
Function EncryptString(ByVal unkString) As String
    Dim encryptedString As String = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(unkString)
        encryptedString += "*"
    Next
    Return encryptedString
End Function
```

This is a cleaner and more reusable way than modifying a field, an argument passed ByRef, or the underlying variable of the function

Comment: The question isn't using a global variable.

Comment: It's better than returning through a ByRef parameter too.

Comment: Is there a reason that it's better than returning through a ByRef parameter, or is it just because it is cleaner?

Comment: It is more "standard".  Encrypting something is logically a function, it takes input, and some single output is expected. `byref` arguments are usually only employed when you don't have any other choice.  It's about structure, and avoiding side-effects.

Comment: If you wanted to return two values from a function, without using a Struct or Class, you could use ByRef

Comment: @esi  A proper function lets you use them in expressions `If BoolFunc(arg1, arg2) Then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your example show one of the multiple reason, who initialize the data is unclear. With your sample code, the first option would append to the passed string while the second would create a new string.

The first method would have to specify if it needs an empty string or explain why it appends. While the second method clearly show that a new string will be returned.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim u, e As String

    u = "123"
    e = "123"

    EncryptString1(u, e)
    Console.WriteLine(e) ' Display: 123***

    u = "123"
    e = "123"

    e = encryptString2(u)
    Console.WriteLine(e) ' Display: ***

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
Sub EncryptString1(ByVal unkString As String, ByRef encryptedString As String)
    For i As Integer = 1 To Len(unkString)
        encryptedString += "*"
    Next
End Sub

Function encryptString2(ByVal unkString As String) As String
    encryptString2 = ""
    For i As Integer = 1 To Len(unkString)
        encryptString2 += "*"
    Next
End Function
```

Please have option strict on. Also, personally, I rather create a variable instead of using the function name, use .Length instead of Len() and concatenate with & instead of +.

```
Function encryptString3(ByVal unkString As String) As String
    Dim encryptedString As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 1 To unkString.Length
        encryptedString &= "*"
    Next

    Return encryptedString
End Function
```

Or just use the New operator of the String class.

```
Dim encryptedString as New String("*"c, unkString.Length)
```

Comment: I think you mean "option strict on", not "option string on".

Answer (score -1):

Well, when I was learning this stuff, it was always to use functions to calculate values and subs to do other stuff.  I guess for something very general, it doesn't really matter which methodology you use, as you have illustrated in your example.  See the link below for further discussion on this topic.

http://analystcave.com/vba-function-vs-vba-sub-procedures/